# How to set API usage limits

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm creating a private RESTful API that is to be consumed by my mobile application. I want to set usage limit to the functions on the basis of users (a client has to register to use the app). I'm confused as to how to achieve that. Do I store API call count against every user, fetch and check it on every request and update it once a request is executed successfully?  Wouldn't it create extraordinary overhead on the server as users start to grow? Is there any faster way to achieve that?

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: I have to think about both the positive and the negative side of things before spending a considerable time in developing this feature, don't I? Hence, the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to record usage against each user, if you are doing for every API method, then this will create exponential data usage per user, and you should consider this when choosing your data-storage method.

I would probably consider a key=>value storage method for this, like redis, and keep this data away from your main data store, so that your throttle validation isn't clogging up the main data server.

Comment: Redis seems like a good idea. And implementing a usage system in memory cache instead of an RDMS database would significantly improve performance as users start growing.

Comment: Redis is impressively fast. I second this.